# jQuery Circles animation on circle path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make big circle and move `div`s along the circle's circumference.

Each `div` must change the content inside the big circle.

The number of `div`(s) must be dependent on how many are fetched from database (from table category).

[**I tried to do this**](http://jsfiddle.net/47Tz9/) and modified the code by putting `.eq()` but the problem with `.eq` is that next circle will appear after that circle, all put in the same place. I want them all to appear at the same time [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/wyW2D/) without repeating functions

Comment: why not just use two.js ? http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/

Comment: i've read about two.js, the problem is that each circle must be a button (or hyperlink) to change something.

Comment: ok so let me get this clear you want your circles to appear all in same place aboce each other , then start to move each to their assigned destination , correct ? using just one function .

Comment: No, i want each circle to move to the assigned destination, and each circle moves in different speed (First one fast, second lower , third lowest ..so on) with one function, and each circle should be clickable.

Comment: yes i understood that , but the initial position where the circles are created is same ? means will tehy be over each other ?

Comment: the initial position is somewhere with (-x,-y) and then start to give each circle new (X,Y), but the coordinates for circle 1 not equal to the coordinates for circle 2 which is not equal to the coordinates for circle 3 .. and so on.

Comment: look at this example : http://jsfiddle.net/wyW2D/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wyW2D/1/

Used:

```
var t = -1.6;
var t2 = -1.6;
var x = 0;
var t = [-1.6, -1.6, -1.6], // starting angle in radians for each circle

    delta = [0.05, 0.03, 0.02], // change in radians for each circle
                                // e.g the first moves fastest, the last 
                                // slowest. if this gets too big, the 
                                // movement won't look circular, since the
                                // animation is really a bunch of straight lines

    finish = [1.4, 1.0, 0.6];   // the stopping point in radians for each
                                // circle. if the circle size changes, this
                                // may need to change

function moveit(i) {
    t[i] += delta[i];    // move the angle forward by delta
    var r = 300;         // radius (the .inner div is 600 x 600)
    var xcenter = -30;   // center X position: this reproduces the .inner horizontal
                                // center but from the body element
    var ycenter = 420;   // center Y position: same here but vertical

    // Basic trig, these use sin/cos to find the vert and horiz offset for a given
    // angle from the center (t[i]) and a given radius (r)
    var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r * Math.cos(t[i])));
    var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(t[i])));

    // Now animate to the new top and left, over 1ms, and when complete call
    // the move function again if t[i] hasn't reached the finish.
    $('div.circle'+(i+1)).animate({
        top: newTop,
        left: newLeft,
    },1, function() {
      if (t[i] < finish[i]) moveit(i);
    });
    // You can slow down the animation by increasing the 1, but that will eventually
    // make it choppy. This plays opposite the delta.
}

// Start the ball rolling
$("document").ready(function(e) {
  moveit(0);
  moveit(1);
  moveit(2);
});
```

This was a quick change to reduce the code to one function that used arrays (t, delta, finish) to keep track of the three circles. It could be improved to accept arbitrary circles, of any size, at any starting / ending angle. 
Also, this kind of animation is much easier with CSS. It is simple to specify and has much better performance.

Comment: By the way, to make them clickable, just add more javascript, or a link in each. Add `$('div.circle1').click(function() { //do something });`

Comment: Thank you, never thought about matrix.

Comment: @noel can you please comment on the other lines of code as to what they are and what they do? I'm trying to get the circle to be at the bottom and full width but having problems getting the circles to work from left to right over the circle

Comment: @MarkP Added comments. Let me know if it is not clear.